# What is the easiest/most elegant way to iterate over matches in a vim script/function?

Tags: vim

I am looking for an elegant solution to (within vim script) iterate over all matches of
a regular expression in a buffer. That would be something like

```
fu! DoSpecialThingsWithMatchedLines()

  for matched_line_no in (GetMatchedPositions("/foo\\>.*\\<bar"))
      let line = getline(matched_line_no)
      call DoItPlease(line)
  end for

endfu
```

Is there something like this? I am not necessarily looking for a full fledged
solution, any pointer directing me into the right direction will do.

Thanks / Rene

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time I'd use michael's solution with `:global`

You can also play with `filter(getline('1','$'), 'v:val =~ "foo\\>.*\\<bar"')` if you really want to use `:for`.

Otherwise, you can simply call `search()` in a loop.

EDIT: 9 years later, in scripts, I'd now use `map()` + `filter()`

```
:call map(filter(getline('1','$'), 'v:val =~ "foo\\>.*\\<bar"'), 'DoItPlease(v:val)')
```

This:

- is much faster than `:for` based solutions,
- is much friendlier to debug (given Vim-script integrated debugger as of today)
- leaves the various registers/history unchanged

Answer (score 5):

you could use :he :global eg.

```
 :%g/foo\\>.*\\<bar/call DoItPlease(getline("."))
```

vimscript example:

```
fun! Doit(line)
    echo a:line
endfun


fun! MyDo()
    %g/foo/call Doit(getline("."))
endfun

:call MyDo()
```

Comment: This approach certainly meets what I functionally want(ed). Yet, I hoped there would be a for .. in construct so that I visually can see what's going on.